# ¿Es posible traducir los mensajes propios de argparse?

Tags: python, localización, argparse

Tengo varios scripts de python de línea de comandos que manejan varios parámetros para invocarlos, esto lo resuelvo mediante [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), lo que es muy sencillo, sin embargo esta librería tiene algunos mensajes en inglés (al menos en python 3.4) que me gustaría traducir, veamos un ejemplo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse

def init_argparse():
    cmdparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='programa', description='descripcion')
    cmdparser.add_argument('archivo', type=str, nargs='?', help="Archivo de input", metavar="\"archivo a interpretar\"")
    cmdparser.add_argument("-v", "--version", action='version', help="mostrar la versión y salir", version="1.1.1")
    return cmdparser

if __name__ == "__main__":

    cmdparser = init_argparse()
    try:
        args = cmdparser.parse_args()
    except IOError as msg:
        cmdparser.error(str(msg))
        sys.exit(-1)
```

Si este Script lo ejecuto como `python miscript.py --help`, obtengo la siguiente salida:

```
usage: programa [-h] [-v] ["archivo a interpretar"]

descripcion

positional arguments:
  "archivo a interpretar"
                        Archivo de input

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --version         mostrar la versión y salir
```

Como se puede observar hay textos como "usage", "positional arguments", "optional arguments" y otros que están en inglés. **¿Como puedo traducirlos para que la interfaz sea consistente?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sé si es la mejor solución, pero lo pude resolver de la siguiente forma:

1. En primer lugar hay que importar [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html?highlight=gettext#module-gettext), el servicio multilenguaje de python
2. Luego hay que crear una rutina propia de traducción, por ej: `my_gettext` y configurar la misma en `gettext.gettext = my_gettext`. Con esto conseguimos controlar el proceso de traducción de las cadenas, previamente debemos investigar qué cadenas son las que vamos a traducir, algunas son tipo "fstrings".
3. La rutina `my_gettext` debería verificar las cadenas que se solicitan traducir y deberíamos reemplazarlas por las versiones que deseemos

Todo esto hay que hacerlo antes de importar `argparse`, también no olvidar asegurarse que el archivo está en utf-8, así terminaría quedando nuestro ejemplo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gettext

def my_gettext(s):
  """my_gettext: Traducir algunas cadenas de argparse."""
  current_dict = {
              'usage: ': 'uso: ',
              'optional arguments': 'argumentos opcionales',
              'show this help message and exit': 'mostrar esta ayuda y salir',
              'positional arguments': 'argumentos posicionales',
              'the following arguments are required: %s': 'los siguientes argumentos son requeridos: %s',
              'show program''s version number and exit': 'Mostrar la versión del programa y salir',
              'expected one argument': 'se espera un valor para el parámetro',
              'expected at least one argument': 'se espera al menos un valor para el parámetro'
  }
  print(s)
  if s in current_dict:
      return current_dict[s]
  return s

#gettext.gettext = my_gettext

import argparse

def init_argparse():
    cmdparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='programa', description='descripcion')
    cmdparser.add_argument('archivo',type=str, nargs='?', help="Archivo de input", metavar="\"archivo a interpretar\"")
    cmdparser.add_argument("-v", "--version",action='version', help="mostrar la versión y salir", version="1.1.1")
    return cmdparser

if __name__ == "__main__":

    cmdparser = init_argparse()
    try:
        args = cmdparser.parse_args()
    except IOError as msg:
        cmdparser.error(str(msg))
        sys.exit(-1)
```

La salida, ahora sí es más consistente:

```
uso: programa [-h] [-v] ["archivo a interpretar"]

descripcion

argumentos posicionales:
  "archivo a interpretar"
                        Archivo de input

argumentos opcionales:
  -h, --help            mostrar esta ayuda y salir
  -v, --version         mostrar la versión y salir
```